# In IE10 running on Windows 7, how can you load an INS file automatically for any user that logs into a machine?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

Prior to IE 10, for any machine-wide options I wanted to set in IE, I would use *Internet Explorer Maintenance* option in the Group Policy Editor. This has been replaced with IE Administrative Templates and/or the IE10 Administration Kit. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj890998.aspx:

> In earlier versions of the Windows® operating system, Internet Explorer Maintenance (IEM) could be used to configure a subset of Internet Explorer 10 settings in an environment using Group Policy. In Windows® 8, the IEM settings have been deprecated in favor of Group Policy Preferences, Administrative Templates (.admx), and the Internet Explorer Administration Kit 10 (IEAK 10).

I downloaded and ran the IEAK, generating an INS file containing all the options I wanted to set (Homepage, Custom Favorites, Proxy Settings, etc) with no problems.

How can I automatically load this INS file for all users that log onto the machine? I thought there was a setting in the IE Administrative Template for me to set the *Use Custom Configuration Script*, but I cannot find it.

**Some Important Details**  I am in a lab setting with all machines on a domain. I AM NOT a domain admin, but my domain account has local admin rights on all the machines in the lab. I can (and do) use the local Group Policy Editor to set several options for the machines. The machines (and the users who log on) have read access to a file server.

Comment: @Tray - Please explain your domain account's permissions in more detail.  How can it not be a domain administrator but have administrator rights on all machines within the domain.

Comment: @Ramhound I mean admin rights on all the machines in that lab.

Comment: Local Administrator or Domain Level `Administrator`.  There is a huge difference and being a local `Administrator` means very little in a domain environment.

Comment: @Ramhound My domain account is in the local Administrators group on each machine, so I have local admin rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here:
http://4sysops.com/archives/internet-explorer-10-administration-part-4-ieak-10/

The Internet Settings files are in a class of their own. These files can be placed on your Corporate Intranet, can be placed in the SIGNUP folder of any Internet Explorer installation and can be fed to Internet Explorer using

```
rundll32.exe iedkcs32.dll,BrandInternetExplorer /ins:<Ins file location>
```

So basically place the file onto a shared network folder, then use a logon script to fire off the above command